# Древовидное меню из инфоблока в Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Ребят подскажите, как вывести в меню элементы раздела инфоблока?. Для решения данной задачи использовал инфоблок каталог, в котором есть разделы (товары 1, товары 2). Далее создал меню sidebar и файл .sidebar.menu_ext, в котором разместил следующий код

```
<? 
  if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die(); 
  global $APPLICATION; 
  $aMenuLinksExt=$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:menu.sections", "", array( 
  "IS_SEF" => "Y", 
  "SEF_BASE_URL" => "/catalog/", 
  "SECTION_PAGE_URL" => "#SECTION_CODE_PATH#/", 
  "DETAIL_PAGE_URL" => "#SECTION_CODE_PATH#/#SECTION_CODE#/", 
  "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "catalog", 
  "IBLOCK_ID" => "1", 
  "DEPTH_LEVEL" => "4", 
  "CACHE_TYPE" => "A", 
  "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000" 
  ), 
false 
); 
  $aMenuLinks = array_merge($aMenuLinksExt, $aMenuLinks); 
?>
```

Далее выбрал шаблон tree, но далее появляется следующая проблема. Появляются разделы инфоблока, но не появляются элементы этого раздела, как это исправить?

Comment: С помощью штатных компонентов никак, читайте курсы и документацию по 1С-Битрикс. Нужно править компонент, чтобы он получал элементы. Вот [здесь рассказывают](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/support/forum/forum6/topic54787/) как это реализовать. Подобные вопросы сначала ищите на профильных форумах.

Comment: примерчик бы........

Comment: Вам нужно объединить массив полученный с помощью `menu.sections` с массивом полученным через `CIBlockElement::GetList`. Пробуйте, не получится кидайте Ваш код, будем смотреть.

Comment: @НиколайСарры https://ideone.com/twzfnF  привел пример кода но тут у меня получается результирующий массив содержит сначала названия разделов а после элементы раздела,как сделать так чтобы после каждого раздела были выведены элементы каждого раздела
    раздел1
   --элементы раздела1
    раздел2
   --элементы раздела2

Comment: модифицируйте `result_modifier.php` или `template.php` компонента `menu.sections` чтобы в нем был `CIBlockElement::GetList` кроме выбора разделов.

Comment: я написал вот так https://ideone.com/1J8irz, а как теперь вывести элементы под разделом?